# Create the type based on the function signature in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that should take a function and return the function with the same parameters list

```
const fn1 = (id: string) => {};
const fn2 = (key: string; value: string) => {};

const caller = <F = ??, A = ??>(fn: F, args: { ?? A }) => {
  fn(...args);
  const recall = (...p: A) => fn(...p);
  return recall;  
}

caller(fn1, { id: '123' });
const recall = caller(fn1, { key: '1', value: '2' });
recall('1', '2');
```

Is there a way to infer function/argument types from arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by providing the arguments to your callback either as a single array value, or serially using spread syntax.

> You can decide which syntax fits your preference, but here's an observation: by using the array syntax, the compiler treats the args as a tuple and preserves label information, but doesn't seem to do so using spread syntax (tested in TS v`4.5.2`). Perhaps this will change in a future release, as the label information is great for developer experience.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=37&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgFBSgBQIYCcMFsDOUEAHsBHACaECucA1nAPYDucA2gLpQC8UGcITgBoUUAEoR81ADbAefASIB88gBQA6TWGx58ALnQ6CASh4qJU2QG4kSAPR2+WHCCcBzfEgBmtAMbAAS0Y4KF8MaWkILABBZyhkVBgiUnIqWDgRVDRkskpCTBxcCDIsfAQYJUzxHNTCCWBqLDgAFXAIcsqkJVUvOAMYIXd9dGN+xDRBsRUAb1FejU1sD2MbVCxixpCF9TADNFNuFXnNHZWkAF9bByh8MHWMCiHvP0Dg0PDIrABlO4gH+NESRIuTS8Cq2WBtUMhWKUTKFSqYhqeXEGyarUgHWUPT6sEGJyWw32YwQE3EMzmcG2hLOazRWxOuxGZigxy0Z0uSF8wXwcl6AEY1AEKAZeVgAnA3AcZucbNy4LzWXAAExqOgQECi4DiyWDABu4WoEC1OqlLOmsqujmwLieYQiUViWBx-MGbAA5PzlQBmd0cM7yxXre3SJ3yEOO5w45Vuz3uwbu5V+s7Bj5O1RxhNJs72Ry3e6PQlcj5RH4Fl0Jr2+gM8uSpiJlv6PXgR76-B7RyvxqCJ90piAhxsdzM97M2IA)

```ts
type Fn<
  Params extends unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = (...params: Params) => Result;

// array args
function callerArr <
  F extends Fn,
  P extends Parameters<F>,
  R extends ReturnType<F>,
>(fn: F, args: P): Fn<P, R> {
  fn(...args);
  return (...p: P) => fn(...p);
}

// spread args
function callerSpread <
  F extends Fn,
  P extends Parameters<F>,
  R extends ReturnType<F>,
>(fn: F, ...args: P): Fn<P, R> {
  fn(...args);
  return (...p: P) => fn(...p);
}

const fn1 = (id: string) => {};
const fn2 = (key: string, value: string) => {};

// array args
callerArr(fn1, ['123']);
const recallArr = callerArr(fn2, ['1', '2']);
recallArr('1', '2');

// spread args
callerSpread(fn1, '123');
const recallSpread = callerSpread(fn2, '1', '2');
recallSpread('1', '2');
```

Comment: @captain-yossarian I'm pretty sure it's generics with function expression syntax during variable assignment that breaks the syntax highlighter, but `lang-ts` is canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: you are right, because highlighting still does not work. Sorry for confusing you with this edit. Good answer!

Comment: my concern is `any[]` as it erases the type information for the `fn`. is that possible to have a generic that would preserve types? as I want to have a strict types checking

Comment: Sure, that type just means “function-like”, but you can replace it with a narrower function type if you want to be more restrictive about what types of functions will be accepted. It shouldn’t affect the inference, though.

Comment: I was looking for some solution using `infer` operator in Typescript, so the type is literally will not be lost because of the `any`.

Comment: Nothing's being lost due to any existing types: there just isn't an explicit return type (which would be `(...a: A) => ReturnType<F>`). I'll update the answer to include one, and I'll refactor the parameters using an additional generic (which you can then reuse) to increase readability.

Comment: @deeptowncitizen Updated. Does that now answer your question satisfactorily?